# operations on character pointers

Tags: c, gcc

I came across a code as in below

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   char a[]="0123456789";
   printf("%s\n",a+6[a]-2[a]);
   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
456789
```

How does the calculation of **a+6[a]-2[a]** happens in printf?

Why giving just 6[a] in printf doesn't work?

```
printf("%s\n",6[a]);
```

Comment: `6[a]` is just a weird way to write `a[6]`. But `printf("%s\n",a+a[6]]-a[2]);` is nonsense anyway.

Comment: Bear in mind that the calculation doesn't ``happen in printf``, the address (for that is what is being generated), is calculated by the compiler, and pushed onto the stack at runtime as a ``parameter`` to printf.

Comment: That expression is just an obfuscated curiosity, and not something to be taken seriously.

Comment: If it helps, for any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is exactly equal to `*(a + i)`. The `6[a]` syntax comes from [the commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of `+`: `a[6]` is equal to `*(a + 6)` which is equal to `*(6 + a)` which is then equal to `6[a]`. The rest is just pointer arithmetic (remember that arrays naturally decays to *pointers* to their first element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a statement like

```
  a+6[a]-2[a]
```

can be re-written as

```
 &(a[ a[6] - a[2] ])
```

which is simply,

- use the value of `a[6]` (type, `int`) as the index in the first case
- use the value of `a[2]` (type `int`) as the RHS.

The result, is a pointer, is passed to `printf()` as an argument to `%s` conversion specification.